# Do places where the Mishkan stood retain Keddushah?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mishkan-tabernacle

The Mishkan wandered through tens of camps in the desert and a couple of places in Israel for 480 years, and Holy Services were held in each place.

Are those places sanctified in any way nowadays? Do any limitations apply to those places?

For example, [Mishkan Shiloh](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94) in Israel.

Comment: I’d assume no, based on Rambam Hil. Beis HaBechirah 6:16, who quotes a derasha unique to the Beis HaMikdash.

Comment: @DonielF I'd also assume that there's no Keddusha, based on how freely people walk around that place (visited personally a couple of times), but why?

Comment: Perhaps since the definition of a Mishkan is to be temporary, it was never קידשה לעתיד לבא? Even בית ראשון according to Rav Nachman was only קידשה לשעתא.